# Why am I having issues with Video.js playing in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video, video.js, audiovideoplayback

Below is the code I am using for the video tag. I basically copy and pasted it off of the Video.js website (then updated with my own file names). At first I could get Chrome to work but not Firefox or Internet Explorer. Then I changed the "webm" tags to "web". This fixed issue with Firefox, but I still can't get any playback with IE9. It just shows up as if it trying to load. Right now I am simply trying to test it out using local files in the same root folder, so I don't think it is an issue with waiting for it to download. My video files range from 8.1 to 8.4 meg.

If anyone has any ideas one how to get this to play, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The following is in the head tag:

```
    `<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="video.js"></script>
    <script>
          _V_.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf"`
    </script>
```

The following is in the html tag:

```
            `<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
              controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  
              poster="bdg-vid-poster.png"  
              data-setup='{}'>  
             <source src="bdg112412hr.mp4" type='video/mp4' />  
             <source src="bdg112412.web" type='video/web' />  
             <source src="bdg112412.ogv" type='video/ogv' />
             </video>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you changed the name from `webm` to `web` - `webm` is the proper extension to use. That line should read:

```
<source src="bdg112412.webm" type='video/webm' />
```

Do you have valid video files for each of the three video types (mp4, web, and ogv)? What happens when you drag and drop the mp4 directly into IE9? Try the webm in Chrome and the ogv in Firefox.

If you are not certain your video files are valid, try downloading the [sample files here](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html). (See the "Download Video" links under the video).

Answer (score 0):

Also helpful for me was the preload="auto" had to be preload="none" or else it waited to load the entire video before playing...a real drag...

Answer (score 0):

Check the mime-type configured on the server.

I had problems with mp4 and IE9. And i just had to change the myme-tipe from **video/mpeg** to **video/mp4**.